# Is there any New-WebServiceProxy alternative?

Tags: powershell, soap, soap-client, powershell-v6.0

I'm trying to consume a SOAP web service at PowerShell 6. I used to do this task with the `New-WebServiceProxy` command on early versions but no longer exists on PowerShell 6. Is there any similar command?

Comment: PowerShell Core is not feature complete as Windows PowerShell is.  What is your reason for using v6?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using currently *PowerShell 7* and the lack of **New-WebServiceProxy** affect me in several Scripts that was running with this *CmdLet* as expected in *PS 5.1*.

As '**danno**' answered before, **Invoke-WebRequest** is the natural option in *Core editions*.

Googling I found two sites with examples to implement a workaround for SOAP Web Services:

https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/getting-started-soap-based-web-services-and-powershell

... and ...

https://www.powershellbros.com/send-soap-message-powershell/

Maybe someone says it that this is go back, but really works!

Answer (score 1):

A combination of [ConvertTo-XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-xml?view=powershell-6) with [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-WebRequest?view=powershell-6) should be able to get you where you need to be, both of which are supported in PowerShell 6.

Comment: It's unlikely that ConvertTo-Xml would be useful.